# Error 0x8007000e in LookupAccountSid()

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I've got a quite old VS6 app that is generating error 0x8007000E (ERROR_OUTOFMEMORY "Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.") in a call to LookupAccountSid.

The call that fails is just trying to determine how large the buffers need to be to use in a second call to LookupAccountSid:

```
std::string GetNameFromSID(PSID pSid)
{
    if (NULL == pSid)
        return "";

    DWORD        _dwName;   //Size of the name in TCHARs
    DWORD        _dwDomain; //Size of the domain in TCHARs
    SID_NAME_USE _use;      //Usage type of the name (user,group etc).
    BOOL         _b;

    //Determine the buffer sizes we require
    SetLastError(0);
    _b = LookupAccountSid( NULL, pSid, NULL, &_dwName, NULL, &_dwDomain, &_use );
    if ( !_b ) {
        DWORD _dw = GetLastError();
        if ( ERROR_NONE_MAPPED == _dw ) {
            //There is no name for this SID
            return "";
        } else if ( ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER == _dw ) {
            //This is expected.
        } else if ( S_OK != _dw ) {
            //This is where we see ERROR_OUTOFMEMORY
            return "";
        }
    }
    //Do some other stuff here...
}
```

What I expected was error 0x8007007A : ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER "The data area passed to a system call is too small." Which would indicate that I (unsurprisingly) needed to allocate larger buffers.

The system is not low on memory at all, so can anybody suggest a cause?

Comment: Could you post some more of the code? Variable declarations, initialisation and where `GetLastError()` is invoked after failure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if it works if you properly initialize `_dwName` and `_dwDomain` to 0.

There might be some random garbage on the stack, but according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379166(v=vs.85).aspx these have to be actually set to 0 to receive required buffer sizes

Comment: Agree: From MSDN: On input, specifies the size, in TCHARs, of the lpReferencedDomainName buffer. If the function fails because the buffer is too small or if cchReferencedDomainName is zero, cchReferencedDomainName receives the required buffer size, including the terminating null character.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks. That'll teach me to actually read the documentation rather than just glance at it.